# How can I print 'hello world!' without utilizing a data segment?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm tinkering with the Keystone assembly engine which lets you assemble instructions in various programming languages (Python 3 in my case), but it's not designed (as far as I can tell) to handle assembly of entire programs (which would make sense, every assembler has its own features) but rather just raw assembly instructions. So this works:

```
from keystone import *
ks = Ks(KS_ARCH_X86, KS_MODE_64)
CODE = b"MOV eax, 0x1; INT 0x80"
X86_CODE64, count = ks.asm(CODE)
```

but setting code to this NASM 'hello world' Assembly example, like:

```
CODE = '''section .text                   ;section declaration

                                ;we must export the entry point to the ELF linker or
    global  _start              ;loader. They conventionally recognize _start as their
                                      ;entry point. Use ld -e foo to override the default.

_start:

                                ;write our string to stdout

    mov     edx,len             ;third argument: message length
    mov     ecx,msg             ;second argument: pointer to message to write
    mov     ebx,1               ;first argument: file handle (stdout)
    mov     eax,4               ;system call number (sys_write)
    int     0x80                ;call kernel

                                ;and exit

    mov     ebx,0               ;first syscall argument: exit code
    mov     eax,1               ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int     0x80                ;call kernel

section .data                   ;section declaration

msg db      "Hello, world!",0xa ;our dear string
len equ     $ - msg             ;length of our dear string'''
```

... does not.

So I would like to test a hello world program out in Assembly, but I'm fairly new to the language and don't understand how to use a string without the typical `msg db "Hello, world!",0xa`

Comment: You can put that into the `.text` section as that works just fine for read-only data. Alternatively, you can create the text on the stack at runtime.

Comment: The other standard way (e.g. for shellcode) is to use `push imm32` to construct things on the stack.  `mov ecx, esp` after a few pushes.

Comment: @PeterCordes tyty, you're a titan on this site in the low-level topic space as per usual. Never going to miss a chance to say thank you and every one who's shared knowledge to  help the next generations of developers reach maximum potential, you guys are legends.